# Use spatial search to count the total number of my users

Tags: solr, gis, geospatial

I am trying to describe my question through a picture.

[image: Image1]

This is my data format.

[image: Image2]

I would like to know how to achieve such statistics in the solr?

I would like to solr achieve the following way t-sql query.

```
 SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(hl_user_info_copy.location)
        FROM
            hl_user_info_copy
        WHERE
            location > 3
    ) AS 'where_1_count',
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(hl_user_info_copy.location)
        FROM
            hl_user_info_copy
        WHERE
            location > 2
        AND location < 3
    ) AS 'where_2_count'
FROM
    hl_user_info_copy
LIMIT 1
```

**t-sql query result：**

```
where_1_count       where_2_count 
4832                4560
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem and shared my code.

https://github.com/WongLeslie/spatial_search_in_solr